# Undefined method in ActionMailer class with ApplicationHelper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

### application_helper.rb

```
class ApplicationHelper

  def user_name(user)
    if user.name.length > 2
      return user.name
    else
      return user.email
    end
  end

  ...

end
```

### class ForumMailer < ActionMailer::Base

```
class ForumMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  add_template_helper(ApplicationHelper)

  @username = user_name(User.find_by_id(1))
end
```

### Error

NoMethodError: undefined method `user_name` for #

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `helper :application`

```
class ForumMailer < ActionMailer::Base
helper :application # include application helper

.....
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guest is that you have not included your application_helper.rb anywher yet.
Try require the helper at the first line of your forum_mailer.rb file:

```
require './path/to/application_helper'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use helpers inside instance methods, not inside the class.